# Why are these rspec tests "pending"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm creating a Rails app and just added a file (**app/spec/models/test_spec.rb**
)with 5 new rspec tests:

```
describe Topic do
   describe "scopes" do

     before do 
       @public_topic = Topic.create # default is public
       @private_topic = Topic.create(public: false)
     end

     describe "publicly_viewable" do
       it "returns a relation of all public topics" do
         expect(Topic.publicly_viewable).to eq( [@public_topic] )
       end
     end

     describe "privately_viewable" do
       it "returns a relation of all private topics" do
         expect(Topic.privately_viewable).to eq( [@private_topic] )
       end
     end

     describe "visible_to(user)" do
       it "returns all topics if the user is present" do
         user = User.new
         expect(Topic.visible_to(user)).to eq(Topic.all)
       end

       it "returns only public topics if user is nil" do
         expect(Topic.visible_to(nil)).to eq(Topic.publicly_viewable)
       end
     end
  end
end
```

When I ran "rspec spec" in the console, I got the following output:

Finished in 8.38 seconds (files took 1 minute 40.84 seconds to load)
18 examples, 1 failure, 5 pending

Why are these 5 examples "pending"?

Comment: the `rspec spec` command should tell you which tests are pending. are you sure they are these?

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, while I'm working on a particular piece of functionality, I like to run only the unit test for that piece. So instead of `rspec spec`, I'd use `rspec 'spec/models/test_spec.rb' -fd`. Then, once my unit test is passing, I'd do the full suite, integration testing, etc. BTW, the `-fd` give you nice output formatting.

Comment: @jvillian - thanks for your reply. When I run `rspec 'spec/models/test_spec.rb' -fd` I get this output: _/home/nitrous/code/bloccit/spec/models/topic_spec.rb:1:in <top (required)>: uninitialized constant Topic (NameError)
        from /home/nitrous/code/project/.bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1327:in load
        from /home/nitrous/code/bloccit/.bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1327:in block in load_spec_files
        from /home/nitrous/code/bloccit/.bundle/gems/rspec-core-... _

Comment: Try changing your first line there to `RSpec.describe Topic, type: :model do`. Currently, you aren't telling RSpec that this is a model spec.

Comment: Also, is this your actual spec file? You're missing `require 'rails_helper'`. And, I think you need to do `before(:each) do` or `before(:all) do` instead of just `before do`. If this is not the entire file, then please post the whole thing.

Comment: @jvillian - when using `before do`, it is implicitly using `before(:each) do` (at least with every version of RSpec I've personally used). Good catch on the missing `require`.

Comment: @MichaelCruz - fair enough of the `before do` bit. Guess I'm a bit of a belt-and-suspenders type when things aren't going well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rspec automatically creates specs for you in other sub-directories of `spec/`. You are running the spec on the whole `spec/` directory, which includes the auto-generated controller specs, view specs, route specs, etc. These come with pending examples. If you only want to run the specs in this file, run `rspec spec/models/test_spec.rb`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! When I run `rspec spec/models/test_spec.rb` I get this output: _/home/nitrous/code/project/spec/models/topic_spec.rb:1:in <top (required)>: uninitialized constant Topic (NameError)
        from /home/nitrous/code/project/.bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1327:in load
        from /home/nitrous/code/bloccit/.bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1327:in block in load_spec_files
        from /home/nitrous/code/bloccit/.bundle/gems/rspec-core-... _

Comment: See my comment on the OP.